# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, oracle11g

When i try to create the following procedure im gettin this error:"PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:" 
I cant find where i went wrong, Help me out for resolving this issue.

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE  ProcName
(inTid IN VARCHAR2,outtxnstatus OUT CHAR,outrowcount OUT NUMBER,outretvalue OUT NUMBER) AS
   CURSOR c1 IS 
    select TXN_STATUS from OP_TTERMINALMASTER where TERMINAL_ID = inTid and TXN_STATUS = 'N' FOR UPDATE OF TXN_STATUS;
    outrowcount:= sql%rowcount;
    BEGIN
    if outrowcount = 1 then
      Open c1;
      fetch c1 into outtxnstatus;   
      update OP_TTERMINALMASTER set TXN_STATUS = 'Y' where current of c1;
      outretvalue := 5;
      CLOSE c1;
    END IF;
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      outretvalue := -5;
    END;
```

Comment: Does it say what symbols it *was* expecting? Does it tell you a line/column number?

Comment: @Gabe its saying like this PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: constant exception <an identifier>

Answer (score 3):

I think it's here (before the `BEGIN`):

```
outrowcount:= sql%rowcount;
```

You declared a cursor in the right place, but then, before the `begin` part you trird to assign `sql%rowcount` before even opening the cursor...

Try

```
 create or replace PROCEDURE  ProcName
(inTid IN VARCHAR2,outtxnstatus OUT CHAR,outrowcount OUT NUMBER,outretvalue OUT NUMBER) AS

   BEGIN

     update OP_TTERMINALMASTER set TXN_STATUS = 'Y'
      where TERMINAL_ID = inTid and TXN_STATUS = 'N';

     outrowcount:= sql%rowcount;

      outretvalue := 5;
   EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      outretvalue := -5;
   END;
```

Comment: but cade i want to see the affected rows of select TXN_STATUS from OP_TTERMINALMASTER where TERMINAL_ID = inTid and TXN_STATUS = 'N'   FOR UPDATE OF TXN_STATUS; HOW TO DO THAT?

Comment: @user1, if you expect only one row then you don't need an explicit cursor (see my updated answer). If for some reason you do want to use a cursor, then you can open the cursor first and then count how many rows you've found, but still, you'll need to loop on the cursor

Comment: @Cade i want to use cursor because i have to lock that particular row which im getting from "SELECT", i want to check for the condition with rowcount coz i dont want to unnecessarily open the cursor, if its o rows affected, opening the cursor for fetching data wont make any sense right. If you have any idea please share.Thanks.

Comment: @user1, you must open a cursor - explicitly or implicitly - if you want to check which rows will be affected. Since you locked the record in your code only for the update, then using one update command *can* have the same effect

Comment: @cade thank you and i didnt get this  "then using one update command can have the same effect"

Comment: @user1, basically oracle doesn't lock records for "reading" this is why it makes sense to add `for update` in a cursor, but it does lock the records when you "update", this is why if you use my code you don't realy nead to lock the record - it's locked automatically. Try this: open 2 sessions and run the same update command on both of them (without commiting), see what's happening. BTW, there is a difference if you use the `nowait` keyword after the `for update`

Comment: Session1: SQL>select * from dept where deptno =10 for update nowait; Session2: SQL>select * from dept where deptno =10 for update nowait; ERROR at line 1: ORA-00054: resource busy and acquire with NOWAIT specified or timeout expired!!!!>> But in my case i should give permission only to select, update should not happen at the same time from other session.If i use nowait select stmnt ll also fail right?

Comment: @user1, I'm not sure that I understand your last comment- if you state `nowait` then the second session that tries to update gets an exception, otherwise it'll wait until first session commits. You need to choose whatever suits your requirements best